# Sort object elements by string, where each string is an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an object where each string contains an array:

```
var users = {
    name   : ["joe" , "tim" , "bob" , "joe"],
    age    : [23    ,  22   ,  21   ,  20  ],
    other  : ["AA"  , "BB"  , "CC"  , "DD"]
}
```

How can I sort these elements, for example by age, so I get this as a result?

```
var users = {
    name   : ["joe" , "tim" , "bob" , "joe"],
    age    : [ 20   ,  21   ,  22   ,  23  ],
    other  : ["DD"  , "CC"  , "BB"  , "AA" ]
}
```

I nserted a duplicate name on purpose, since it should work in cases like these (should keep the relationship positions).

Note: In case someone else has this same issue, after reading the answers I now recommend changing the data structure to:

```
var users = [ // note this is now an array
    name   : {"joe" , "tim" , "bob" , "joe"},
    age    : {23    ,  22   ,  21   ,  20  },
    other  : {"AA"  , "BB"  , "CC"  , "DD"}
]
```

This way, more simple approaches like .sort can be used.

Comment: Without quotes those are not strings. They will be evaluated as undefined variables. Therefore the sample does not qualify as a [mcve] and would require anyone who wanted to help to add quotes themselves. Beyond that - show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service

Comment: yes, sorry, those are strings I wrote it wrong in here. going to correct this.

Comment: @user1582208 in your original question, the names stay the same order while the ages change order. Was that intentional? In the array, it appears `tim` is `22` and in the second, `tim` is `21`. Is that correct?

Comment: @user1582208 I provided several different examples in my solution. Please take time to check each. The first example simply does what you're looking for using your sample data, and my final solution `sortBy('age')` works dynamically to take all properties into account and sort by whichever you want, in ascending order (default) or descending order (set 2nd param to `true`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can take the data you are starting with and create a new array of objects where we map each individual to their assigned age, and then we sort that array of objects by its `age` property value:

```js
let users = {
  name: ["joe", "tim", "bob", "joe"],
  age: [23, 22, 21, 20]
};

const associateUserDetails = users => Array(users.name.length).fill().map((e,i) => ({name: users.name[i], age: users.age[i]})).sort((a,b) => a.age - b.age);

console.log(associateUserDetails(users));
/* -> [
        { name: "joe", age: 20 },
        { name: "bob", age: 21 },
        { name: "tim", age: 22 },
        { name: "joe", age: 23 }
      ]
*/
```

Once we this array of users sorted by their age, all that's left to do is split the array of objects back up into two nested arrays for `name` and `age`, like this:

```js
let users = {
  name: ["joe", "tim", "bob", "joe"],
  age: [23, 22, 21, 20]
};

const associateUserDetails = users => Array(users.name.length).fill().map((e,i) => ({name: users.name[i], age: users.age[i]})).sort((a,b) => a.age - b.age);

const splitByDetail = users => users.flatMap(user => Object.entries(user)).reduce((a,c) => (a[c[0]] ? a[c[0]].push(c[1]) : a[c[0]] = [c[1]], a), {});

console.log(splitByDetail(associateUserDetails(users)));
/* -> {
        name: ["joe", "bob", "tim", "joe"],
        age: [20, 21, 22, 23]
      }
*/
```

Now let's combine this all together:

```js
let users = {
  name: ["joe", "tim", "bob", "joe"],
  age: [23, 22, 21, 20]
};

const sortUsersByAge = users => Array(users.name.length).fill().map((e,i) => ({name: users.name[i], age: users.age[i]})).sort((a,b) => a.age - b.age).flatMap(user => Object.entries(user)).reduce((a,c) => (a[c[0]] ? a[c[0]].push(c[1]) : a[c[0]] = [c[1]], a), {});

console.log(sortUsersByAge(users));
/* -> {
        name: ["joe", "bob", "tim", "joe"],
        age: [20, 21, 22, 23]
      }
*/
```

### BONUS

Now for a bonus— let's say you have an object like the one you provided and…

- are working with many more user details, maybe even a variable number of details, and you would rather list them all explicitly
- want the ability to sort by any of the user details listed, name (alphabetical sorting), age (numerical sorting), ID number (numerical sorting), or some other property (default to alphabetical sorting unless all values are numbers)
- would like to add a boolean true/false switch to quickly reverse the order of any sorting function like `sortUsers(users, true)` where the second parameter would reverse each final array's state after sorting
- you want to use this function as an `Object.prototype` method, like `users.sortBy('age')` instead of `sortObject(users, 'age')`

Let's make all of those improvements and put it all together into one prototype function `Object.sortBy()`:

```js
let users = {
  name: ["joe", "tim", "bob", "joe"],
  age: [23, 22, 21, 20],
  color: ["blue", "green", "red", "yellow"]
};

Object.prototype.sortBy = function(sortBy, descending = false) { return sortBy && Object.keys(this).includes(sortBy) ? [Array(this[Object.keys(this)[0]].length).fill().map((e,i) => Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(this).map(key => [key, this[key][i]])))].map(obj => obj.sort((a,b) => obj.every(user => typeof user[sortBy] === "number") ? a[sortBy] - b[sortBy] : (a[sortBy] > b[sortBy] ? 1 : -1)))[0].flatMap(user => Object.entries(user)).reduce((a,c) => (a[c[0]] ? a[c[0]].push(c[1]) : a[c[0]] = [c[1]], a), {}) : this };

users.sortBy('age');
/* -> {
        name: ["joe", "bob", "tim", "joe"],
        age: [20, 21, 22, 23],
        color: ["yellow", "red", "green", "blue"]
      }
*/

users.sortBy('name');
/* -> {
        name: ["bob", "joe", "joe", "tim"],
        age: [21, 20, 23, 22],
        color: ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green"]
      }
*/

users.sortBy('color', true); // true here will sort colors by name in descending order
/* -> {
        name: ["joe", "bob", "tim", "joe"],
        age: [20, 21, 22, 23],
        color: ["yellow", "red", "green", "blue"]
      }
*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really really good!

Comment: @user1582208 Thanks, glad to hear it! If this worked for you, would you consider selecting my answer as the correct solution?

Comment: Sure! your answer didn't only solve my problem, but made me realize I could have set up the objects like that from the start (one array with many objects, instead of one object with many arrays).
Very noob of my part I see now, but Ireceived it like that and ended up going with it. I am now rewriting a lot of code but it will be MUCH better. Thanks for helping out a newbie

Comment: @user1582208 I'm really glad it helped! I thoroughly enjoyed writing it and exploring your object setup as well :)

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation** Provided all the values in the object are arrays.

1. Firstly, duplicate the original array to prevent changing the original object.
2. Using a `while` loop to find the index of the smallest passed property using the `Math.min` function.
3. Splicing the `index` from all the keys of the passed object and pushing it into the new object.

```js
let users = {name:["joe", "tim", "bob", "joe"], age:[23, 22, 21, 20], other  : ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"]};

function sortObject(obj, prop) {
  obj = {...obj}; // To avoid changing the initial object
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const newObj = keys.reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b] = [];
    return a;
  }, {});

  while (obj[prop].length) {
    const index = obj[prop].findIndex(age => age == Math.min(...obj[prop]));

    keys.forEach(key => newObj[key].push(obj[key].splice(index, 1)[0]));
  }

  return newObj;
}

console.log(sortObject(users, 'age'));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is group the user names by age in a Map or object keyed by ages.

Then after sorting the ages, map the ages array to names array plucking the name values from the groupBy object/Map

```js
var users = {
  name: ["bob", "joe", "tim", "bob", "joe"],
  age: [20, 23, 22, 21, 20]// added duplicate age also
}
// Map using ages as keys , empty array for values
const grouped = new Map(users.age.map((age, i) => [age, []]))
// push each name to appropriate age array in map
users.name.forEach((name, i) => grouped.get(users.age[i]).push(name));

const sortedAges = users.age.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b),
      // rebuild names array from items in Map
      sortedNames = sortedAges.map(age => grouped.get(age).shift());

const sortedUsers = {
  name:sortedNames, 
  age: sortedAges
}


for(prop in sortedUsers){
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedUsers[prop]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now found this:

```
/**
 *  Sorts all arrays together with the first. Pass either a list of arrays, or a map. Any key is accepted.
 *     Array|Object arrays               [sortableArray, ...otherArrays]; {sortableArray: [], secondaryArray: [], ...}
 *     Function comparator(?,?) -> int   optional compareFunction, compatible with Array.sort(compareFunction) 
 */
function sortArrays(arrays, comparator = (a, b) => (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0) {
  let arrayKeys = Object.keys(arrays);
  let sortableArray = Object.values(arrays)[0];
  let indexes = Object.keys(sortableArray);
  let sortedIndexes = indexes.sort((a, b) => comparator(sortableArray[a], sortableArray[b]));

  let sortByIndexes = (array, sortedIndexes) => sortedIndexes.map(sortedIndex => array[sortedIndex]);

  if (Array.isArray(arrays)) {
    return arrayKeys.map(arrayIndex => sortByIndexes(arrays[arrayIndex], sortedIndexes));
  } else {
    let sortedArrays = {};
    arrayKeys.forEach((arrayKey) => {
      sortedArrays[arrayKey] = sortByIndexes(arrays[arrayKey], sortedIndexes);
    });
    return sortedArrays;
  }
}
```

Example:

```
let people = ["john", "benny", "sally", "george"];
let peopleIds = [10, 20, 30, 40];

sortArrays([people, peopleIds]);
[["benny", "george", "john", "sally"], [20, 40, 10, 30]] // output

sortArrays({people, peopleIds});
{"people": ["benny", "george", "john", "sally"], "peopleIds": [20, 40, 10, 30]} // output
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/boukeversteegh/3219ffb912ac6ef7282b1f5ce7a379ad